# I'm having a hard time understanding and implementing a constructor and I'm looking for some guidance

Tags: java

I'm learning about constructors, but the videos that I've watched don't seem to help and everything I find on google seems to describe it in an advanced way.

I want to write a simple program which takes two inputs, a name (String) and an id (integer) and then just outputs it as "id" - "name". So for example:

```
01 - hello
```

This is the program that I'm trying to fix:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConstructorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConstructorTest();
        toString(null);
    }

    //Constructor
    public ConstructorTest(){
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner id = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    // Method
    public String toString(String name, int id) {
        System.out.print(id + " - " + name);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The errors that I get, are saying that my methods and constructors are undefined.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of the error for future readers. To invoke a constructor you need to use `new`. Then use the object that is created to call your other methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constructor creates ("constructs") a new object. You can then call methods against that object.

Here's a simple object:

```
public class MyObject {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  public MyObject(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
  // Other methods here, for example:
  public void print() {
    System.out.println(id + " " + name);
  }
}
```

You would call this constructor like this:

```
MyObject thing = new MyObject(1, "test");
```

And then you could call its method like this:

```
thing.print();
```

So for your example, what you'd do in your main method is first prompt the user for id and name, then create an object using a constructor, and then call a method on the constructor.

```
public class ConstructorTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // get the id and name from the scanner (I would suggest using prompts)
    String name = in.nextLine();
    int id = in.nextInt();

    // create an object:
    ConstructorTest myObject = new ConstructorTest(id, name);

    // call the method:
    String myString = myObject.toString();

    // print the result:
    System.out.println(myString);
  }

  // private variables, effectively the "properties" stored by the object:
  private int id;
  private String name;

  // constructor:
  public ConstructorTest(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  // method
  @Override // because this is a method in java.lang.Object and we're overriding it
  public String toString() {
    return id + " - " + name;
  }
}
```

Comment: "A constructor creates ("constructs") a new object." This is such a helpful analogy, thank you. So a constructor always has to go along with an object, that was something I didn't quite get in previous tutorials. Can you explain to me what the "this.id" and "this.name" exactly does in the constructor? Thanks

Comment: `this` is a keyword which refers to "this particular instance". It's a useful way to reference the object's variables (id and name) as opposed to a local variable of the same name. Notice that the variables passed into the constructor are *also* named `id` and `name` -- the syntax `this.id = id` says "set the object's id to equal the value of id that was passed in."

Comment: I see, so it's basically a way to "bridge" the variables from the scanner to the constructor by saying they are the same?

Comment: It's a way to differentiate between the value you've passing in (could be from the scanner, but you could also in theory hard-code it or read from a file or pass it in via the command line) and the value that's actually stored within the object itself. If you look at the `toString()` and `print()` implementations, you'll see that the keyword is missing -- that's because it's implied. You only *need* it if you need to differentiate between identically named variables (though some will recommend always doing it as a habit to be explicit.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConstructorTest {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = args[0];
        int id = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
        ConstructorTest ct = new ConstructorTest(name, id);
        System.out.println(ct);
    }

    public ConstructorTest(String n, int i) {
        this.id = i;
        this.name = n;
    }

    // Method
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d - %s", id, name);
    }
}
```

Never, ever put I/O in a constructor.

Comment: You need the `new` keyword on your Constructor invocation